# I'm trying to navigate to tab in lwc but getting error page

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

**HTML**

```
<lightning-button label="VIEW" title="Toggle content action" icon-name={toggleIconName}
                        onclick={handleAction}>
                    </lightning-button>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class NavigatingToTab extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@api pageName = '';
handleAction(event) {
        this.pageName = 'Page__c';
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__navItemPage',
            attributes: {
                apiName: this.pageName,
            },
        });
    }
```

Please let me know what I missed in the code.

Comment: Seems your 'apiName' is not correct. You have to provide the Tab Name here.

Comment: @SarojBera the api name is correct, I reviewed it twice. I'm using this in experience cloud. Does that make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are navigating in an Experience Builder site you should probably be using this:

```
handleAction(event) {
    this.pageName = 'Page__c';
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            name: this.pageName,
        },
    });
}
```